# How to set waiting timeout on JmsMessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-jms, spring-messaging

I'm using sendAndReceive from JmsMessagingTemplate in an MVC controller but if no reply message is sent it seems to keep waiting on a reply forever. The documentation states that:

> Returns:
>   the reply, possibly null if the message could not be received, for example due to a timeout

However I just can't figure out after how long a timeout is given or where to configure this. Can someone explain this to me?

*FYI: I am not using spring-integration but spring-messaging.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can pass [JmsTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/core/JmsTemplate.html) while creating [JmsMessagingTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.1.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/core/JmsMessagingTemplate.html#JmsMessagingTemplate-org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate-)

in `JmsTemplate` you can configure [property](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/core/JmsTemplate.html#setReceiveTimeout-long-) `setReceiveTimeout(long receiveTimeout)` where time is in milliseconds

Comment: Thanks! That solved it. After setting receiveTimeout in JmsTemplate and then passing that to JmsMessagingTemplate it worked

Answer (score -1):

The receive timeout can be configured in the `JmsTemplate` that the `JmsMessagingTemplate` uses.