# How to timeout queueConnectionFactory create connection

Tags: java

I'm facing a timeout while invoking `javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection()`

¿Is there any way to customize timout time for creating connection?

```
javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory; //look up in context here
connectionFactory.createConnection();
```

Comment: This depends to how you connect to jms, for spring you can see https://stackoverflow.com/a/33375798/175554 for ibm mq https://stackoverflow.com/a/51549226/175554

Comment: You should add this as an answer, this totally worked for me. Thanks @özkanpakdil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends to how you connect to jms, for spring you can see [How to set waiting timeout on JmsMessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33375681/how-to-set-waiting-timeout-on-jmsmessagingtemplate-sendandreceive/33375798#33375798) for ibm mq [IBM MQ Connect Factory CLIENTRECONNECTTIMEOUT without using CLIENTRECONNECTOPTIONS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51512443/ibm-mq-connect-factory-clientreconnecttimeout-without-using-clientreconnectoptio/51549226#51549226)